# Reputation change since last visit on user page doesn't pick up Assocation Bonus

Tags: bug, profile-page, association-bonus

I have received the Assocation Bonus just before I went to the reputation-tab on my profile page. The number shown in the tab's title is not correct in relation to the Association Bonus: it does not take it into account. The number I would have expected is 115 instead of 15, as the summation of the number highlighted on the tab is 115.

[image: Screenshot]